# When only one generic parameter is passed in, subsequent generic parameters can also be automatically derived？

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
    interface Option<T> {
      on: (p: T) => T
    }

    function identity<A, B = any> (a: A, b: B, c?: Option<B>) {}

    identity(1,
      {
        a: 1
      },
      {
        on: p => p // At this point, p can be correctly derived as {a: 1}
      }
    )

    identity<number>(1,
      {
        a: 1
      },
      {
        on: p => p // At this point, p is derived as any
      }
    )
```

Is there any way to automatically derive generic B based on the passed in parameter b when only generic A is passed in?

I only thought of the following solution, but it is more invasive

```
    function identity<A> (a: A) {
      return <B>(b: B, c?: Option<B>) => {}
    }

    identity<number>(1)({ a: 1 }, { on: p => p })
```

I am a beginner at TS and am very confused about this issue

Comment: This is a missing feature of TS; there is no *partial type argument inference*.  See linked q/a for more info